# how to use melt and dcast on tough data frame

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

I have a data frame that has one value in each cell, but my last column is a list.
Example. Here there are 3 columns. X and Y columns have one value in each row. But column Z is actually a list. It can have multiple values in each cell.

```
      X Y    Z
    1 a d  h, i, j
    2 b e  j, k
    3 c f  l, m, n, o
```

I need to create this:

```
  X Y    Z
 1 a d  h
 2 a d  i
 3 a d  j
 4 b e  j
 4 b e  k
 5 c f  l
 6 c f  m
 7 c f  n
 8 c f  o
```

Can someone help me figure this out ? I am not sure how to use melt or dcast or any other function for this.

Thanks.

Comment: You just need to unlist by group, something like `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, .(Z = unlist(Z)), by = .(X, Y)]`

Comment: Wow...worked like charm. Could you explain what the code is doing , so I can better understand it ?

Comment: I'd guess the `tidyr` approach is simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unnest` from `tidyr` works

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(dat, Z)
```

Comment: wow...mind blowing !! I can't believe I spent many days trying to write loops and functions, when the solution is just one line !